# When to use callback useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

It's maybe simple question, but the i'm not fully understand `useState`

I have confuse with when to use callback with useState, say example, i have an hook

```
const[count,setCount] = useState(0)
```

We can easy to update, for example , if i want to update the number, i can do:

```
setCount(count+1)
```

But if we have some code like setInterval,we want to increase the count every 1 second, when do the same as above

```
setTimeout(()=>{
 setCount(count+1)
},1000)
console.log(count)
```

It will not increase even 1s passed

But we do

```
 setTimeout(()=>{
     setCount((count)=>{count+1}
    },1000)
    console.log(count)
```

But why it work???

My question is

**When to use callback in useState?**

Comment: the second "But we do" block is not valid JS, and you use setTimeout but write about setInterval

Answer (score 1):

In React, when you update a state property, with respect to its previous value, you
should use,

`setState((state,props)=>{ return doSomethingWith(state.property)})`

In your code (using hooks):
`setCount((count)=>(count+1))`

This is due to the fact that, state updates [may be asynchronous in React](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous).

By the way `setCount((count)=>(count+1))` is not the same as `setCount((count)=>{count+1})`. In the 2nd case, the curly braces form an empty statement, & hence `count+1` is not returned. In lambda functions the *auto-return* happens only in the case of a *single expression*.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever a current state value update depends on the previous state , we can use a callback function.

> if we have some code like setInterval,we want to increase the count every 1 second

For `setInterval`, Each second we need to update the count based on the previous state.This will update the count every 1 second interval.

`setInterval(() => { setCount((count) => count + 1); }, 1000);`

Answer (score 1):

You use the callback when you want to keep the previous state and add something to it.

For example, let's say we have a counter in your case

```js
const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
```

If I want this value to increase every second or when I press a button, I would use the following:

```js
setCounter(prev => (prev + 1);
// Or
setCounter(counter => (counter + 1);
```

`prev` will be the same value as `counter` doesn't matter what you call it.

And since you will be using setInterval you will have to do this operation in a `useEffect` hook is the reason you will need the callback
otherwise if you keep setting the value to `counter + 1` without using the callback you will just be `0 + 1` all the time.

Unless you wanna use it for something like increasing a like button counts. In that case you don't need callbacks.

Try reading and understanding those articles and docs:

- [setInterval in react hooks](https://upmostly.com/tutorials/setinterval-in-react-components-using-hooks)
- [useEffect Hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)